# I am trying to set up Email to Case in my org, but when I try to set up forward settings from my official account, cases are not creating

Tags: email2case

I am trying to set up Email to Case in my org, but when I try to set up forward settings

from my official account, cases are not getting created in Salesforce.

But If I try to send request directly to Email Service Address generated in

Routing information for the respective email id, those emails are getting converted to cases

Any inputs on how to proceed further on this?

Comment: Please add some screenshots to understand the question better.
You need to set-up Routing address and once it is done, you need to route all your emails to that generated email address so it is converted/created as case. You can test that routing address by manually sending an email to that address.

Comment: This is typically done in the mail system (e.g. your corporate Gmail) to establish the forwarding rules. Also check to make sure the email address mysupport@mycompany.com has been verified